# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Tags: python, excel, for-loop

Trying to sum the total of excel cell data inputs ('123.111', '112.1', '123') and then divide them by a count to get the avg. I keep on getting type errors and im not sure why, unless its because the cell data type is not compatible. Also trying to work out the min and max if anyone can help

```
total = 0
count = 0
for cellObj2 in rows2:
    State = str(cellObj2[3].value)
    if 'Queensland' in State:
        newtotal = cellObj2[1].value
        total = newtotal + total

print(total)
```

Comment: i can get all of the data to appear just can add them together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, 
Sometimes I see cellObj2[1].value comes None, So add it only when Its not empty.

```
total = 0
count = 0
for cellObj2 in rows2:
    State = str(cellObj2[3].value)
    if 'Queensland' in State and cellObj2[1].value:
        total += cellObj2[1].value

print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `newtotal` as `None` sometimes. So please add a condition over there. Like

```
.......
if 'Queensland' in State:
        newtotal = cellObj2[1].value
        if newtotal:
            total = newtotal + total
......
```